# Can an initialization be stored as a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables

In JavaScript, is there a way to store an initialization before it is evaluated by the compiler?

For example:
var a = 5*6;

I want to print the string "5*6", not the value the variable a evaluates to.

Comment: No. But you can use a parser like http://esprima.org/ to get an AST of the code and inspect it.

Answer (score 4):

Errr.... then just store the string??

```
var a = "5*6";
```